# Drive is not changing when executing a command line prompt from unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, command-line, cmd, process

I am trying to execute a command line prompt in unity using C#, but first I need to change the drive from `G:\FileOne\Game1` in which the game is stored, to `C:\Users\HP\Documents`, then execute a command that should be under Documents, this is what I have been doing:

```
    ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo ("cmd.exe");
    proc.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    var process = Process.Start (proc);
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"C:");
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Users\HP\Documents");
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine (@"MyCommandLine");
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ();
    print (s);
```

I stored the output to a string variable s and this is what it gets:

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.16299.371]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits r�serv�s.

G:\FileOne\Game1>﻿C:

G:\FileOne\Game1>cd C:\Users\HP\Documents

G:\FileOne\Game1>MyCommandLine

G:\FileOne\Game1>exit
```

The MyCommandLine should create a text file, but the drive as you can see is not changing and the text file is not creating.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just setting the working directory on the ProcessStartInfo?

Comment: Couldn't undrestand what you ment exactly!

Comment: Try using `CD /D "C:\Users\HP\Documents"` to change both the device and directory simultaneously.

Comment: I actually had to change the code, and use work with ProcessStartInfo Class to get it working, thx